# How to parse https url that redirects to another url

Tags: php, parsing, redirect, https

I am trying to parse this URL

https://graph.facebook.com/4/picture?width=378&height=378

but it redirects me to another link:

[https://z-n.ak.fbcdn.net/profile.ak/hprofile-ak-xfp1/v/t1.0-1/p480x480/10390028_10102210419817761_5871103530921178170_n.jpg?oh=9d44ae6370a6481a6e4e5c42d7850e2a&oe=56C84426&**gda**=1455827889_efa267e73eea3dd27aa02526c323a1e6](https://z-n.ak.fbcdn.net/profile.ak/hprofile-ak-xfp1/v/t1.0-1/p480x480/10390028_10102210419817761_5871103530921178170_n.jpg?oh=9d44ae6370a6481a6e4e5c42d7850e2a&oe=56C84426&__gda__=1455827889_efa267e73eea3dd27aa02526c323a1e6)

So the question is I want to implement the code to use the first link and when it redirects to the second link, parse the second one I need to get something from the second URL, what is the best practice?

Thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With CURL:

```
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/4/picture?width=378&height=378';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // follow the redirects
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); // no needs to pass the headers to the data stream
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true); // get the resource without a body
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // accept any server certificate
curl_exec($ch);

// get the last used URL
$lastUrl = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);

curl_close($ch);

echo $lastUrl;
```

Comment: It gave me the same url inside $url

Comment: I've added `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code :

```
    <?php
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/4/picture?width=378&height=378";
$content = get_url_data($url);
$code = $content['code'];
$headers_array = $content['headers_array'];
$redirect_url = '';

if($code == 301  ||  $code == 302){
    $headers = $content['headers_array'];
    if(isset($headers['Location'])){
        $redirect_url = $headers['Location'][0];
    }
}
echo 'Redirected url:' . $redirect_url;



function get_url_data($url, $timeout = 5){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,            $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,  $timeout );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13");

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
    $header = substr($response, 0, $header_size);
    $body = substr($response, $header_size);
    $headers  = explode( "\n", $header );

    $code = 0;
    if(isset($headers[0])){
        if(preg_match('/[0-9]{3}/', $headers[0], $matches)){
            $code = $matches[0];
        }
    }

    $headers_array = [];
    foreach($headers as $h){
        $index = strpos($h, ":");
        if($index !== false){
            $key = trim(substr($h, 0, $index));
            $value = trim(substr($h, ($index+1)));
            $headers_array[$key] = [$value];
        }
    }

    return ['headers' => $headers, 'body' => $body, 'code' => $code, 'headers_array' => $headers_array];
}
```

Comment: It didn't give me any results with https

Comment: oh my by, it was not working because https. Now I added "curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);" now works you can try.

Comment: Actually this works fine with your URL, IS working with HTTP only ? or it doesn't work with subdomains?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help I appreciate it :)

Comment: you can vote up answers if they help you, we will appreciate it :)

Comment: Yes sure when I get 15 of repetition I will.

Answer (score 0):

Try use `get_headers` function

```
<?  
    $link = 'https://graph.facebook.com/4/picture?width=378&height=378';
    $headers = get_headers($link);
    foreach ($headers as $header) {
       if (preg_match('/^Location:\s(.*)/', $header, $out)) {
            echo $out[1];
            break;
       }
    }
```

Comment: This one gave me this error message "Warning: get_headers(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed in D:\xampp\htdocs\facebook-profile-picture-scraper\test.php on line 3"

Comment: for https you need curl.